# Convert Encoding to ANSI

Tags: vbscript

I have been trying to convert a text file with encoding UTF8 to encoding ANSI.
I am using one script that I found in this platform itself.
Below is the script:

```
' Usage: 
' EncodeFile strInFile, "UTF-8", strOutFile, "Windows-1254", 2
Sub EncodeFile(strInputFile, strInputCharset, strOutputFile, strOutputCharset, intOverwriteMode)

'5th parameter may take the following values:
'Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
'Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1

Const adReadLine = -2
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adWriteLine = 1

Set objInputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Set objOutputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

With objInputStream
  .Open
  .Type = adTypeBinary
  .LoadFromFile strInputFile
  .Type = adTypeText
  .Charset = strInputCharset
  objOutputStream.Open
  objOutputStream.Charset = strOutputCharset
  Do While .EOS <> True
     strText = .ReadText(adReadLine)
     objOutputStream.WriteText strText, adWriteLine
  Loop
  .Close
End With
objOutputStream.SaveToFile strOutputFile, intOverwriteMode
objOutputStream.Close
End Sub
```

Please note that while running a cmd that call this script I get a new txt file with 0 kb and the encoding is changed to ANSI.
But all the information within the text file are not present.

How do I convert to encoding while keeping the data in the text file?

Anyone please help.

```
@Echo off

SET CHEMINDAT = C:\Desktop\convertry\Scripts\

echo %DATE% %TIME% Debut de traitement.
for %%a in (C:\Desktop\convertry\Scripts\*.txt) do (
    cscript //NoLogo C:\Desktop\convertry\Scripts\unix2dos_3.vbs <%CHEMINDAT%%%a >>%%a.txt
    del %%a
)
pause
exit /b 1
```

Comment: `EncodeFile "InFile", "UTF-8", "OutFile", "Windows-1254", 2` works for me (I didn't tested `strInputFile`==`strOutputFile` case).

Comment: Can you please explain to me, what it the exact code you used and how did you launch it, I am launching it using a batch script.

Comment: Sorry. _You_ should give a [mcve] of failing code. Please add it using the [edit] feature.

Comment: Hello , you can see my batch script has been added

Comment: **1.** As currently written, the `EncodeFile` procedure is declared but never called _and_ the `vbs` script itself does not accept any argument. **2.**  Remove spaces surrounding the `=` (_Equals Sign_) in  a variable setting: use `SET "CHEMINDAT=C:\Desktop\convertry\Scripts\"`. **3.** The `EncodeFile` procedure itself writes data to a output file and does not produce any output so why the `>>%%a.txt`?